# What is probability?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

I am looking for a definition of probability, specifically of the kind that corresponds to the frequency of repeatable phenomena rather than the epistemic kind.

I have the following idea of what probability is, but I know it is a poor definition. If $P_n = y$ only $X$% of the time, and if the process $P_n$ ($n$ representing a different instance) is repeated many times, each time adding its value to a list $L$, then as the number of times I repeat this grows to infinity, the percentage of values in $L$ which are $y$ should approach $X$%.

The problem with this definition is that it doesn't tell me anything about what I should *expect* after a single trial, or even after arbitrarily many trials since it tells me nothing how the proportion of trials with outcome $y$ should approach $X$%. Furthermore, I don't really know what I mean by $X$% of the time or by the percentage of a infinitely sized list.

I have heard it said that the probability $X$% chance of $Y$ means that $X$% of that phenomena are $Y$. This is uncomfortable because there are cases where one speaks of the probability of a singular event where only one item matches the problem statement, e.g., in quantum mechanics where a specific wavefunction is collapsed.

Comment: [Philosophy SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) will be ableto give you a much better answer than we will

Comment: @BySymmetry It is strange to read that a question on the definition of probability would not be at home at PSE, considering a large part of Physics is based on probabilistic statements. Moreover, mathematicians offer many definitions of probability, but the choice between them  Physics.

Comment: Or maybe: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is the frequentist [view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequentist_probability), but there are others

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to turn some comments into an answer, although I am not sure this is what the OP had in mind, it is how probability is used in (experimental) physics in practice.

There is a [mathematically rigorous definition of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms), but physicists rarely have need for it.

In practice a physicist would object to you saying you don't know anything "even after arbitrarily many trials." In practice, after many we expect the proportion of trials that have property $X$
to match the probability $P(X)$, with some statistical uncertainty that can be calculated and is a function of the number of trials $N$.

There is no guarantee that proportion of outcomes in the list you observe will match $P(X)$ within the expected statistical uncertainty, but you can make the odds "as good as you like" by doing more trials. For physicists, we often require that the observed list could only be produced by our expected probabilities (given some "default model") $0.00002\%$ of the time before we believe that we've calculated the probabilities incorrectly, meaning that we may have discovered something not in the default model. This is a way of stating the "5 sigma" threshold you may have heard of.

In other words: there are no guarantees in experimental physics in the way that a purely mathematical definition of probability would give you a guarantee, but we can make probabilistic statements about what we observe along the lines that "no reasonable person would bet against this" :)

Comment: Your link is deceptive. It does not link to a "mathematically rigorous definition" of probability, but instead to an "axiomatization" of probability. The difference is that a definition would (if you had one) tell you what probability *is*, whereas the axioms in that link (like other mathematical axioms) only tell you how probability *behaves*. I also suspect that every physicist would agree that the probability that they think about does indeed behave as those axioms say probability should behave.

Comment: @LeeMosher "I also suspect that every physicist .... think ...as those axioms say probability should behave." I think that is an exaggeration, some aspects of the standard Kolmogorov axioms are very controversial. Not only De Finetti but other Bayesians strongly disliked countable additivity and its consequences, and tried to replace it with something else. Here is, for example, Prof. Glenn Shafer of "theory of mathematical evidence fame" promoting (rediscovering?) the Cournot [principle](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=shafer%2C+cournot+principle&btnG=)

Comment: Point taken, although that only strengthens my point that the mathematical list of *axioms* of probability is only descriptive, not definitive.